# Edge coloring - Ramsey's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Before covering Ramsey's Theorem, the book gave the following proposition:

> If the 2-subsets of a 9-set are colored yellow and green, there is either a yellow 3-set or a green 4-set.

Then the book tried to first prove this result for 10 points, the proof starts off:

Consider first for 10 points. Consider the nine edges joining one point x to the others. By the Pigeonhole Principle, either there are four yellow edges or six green edges.

But why are there only either four yellow edges or six green edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't **only** four yellow or six green edges, there are **at least** four yellow  or six green edges.  For all we know, they might be all yellow or all green.

Comment: But why is that? Maybe I am drawing the wrong shape because I can't see why that is?

Comment: @Luffy: Suppose that $k$ of the $9$ edges are green; then $9-k$ are yellow. If $k\ge 6$, there are (at least) $6$ green edges. If not, then $k\le 5$, so $9-k\ge 9-5=4$, and there are (at least) $4$ yellow edges. Thus, in every case there are either (at least) $4$ yellow edges or (at least) $6$ green edges.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ohh, I see now. I was thinking something completely different. Thank you! But for the same problem it continues by saying suppose there are four red edges, and let X be the set of their four endpoints other than x. If X contains a red edge yz then xyz is a red triangle. But why is that the case? Since X contains the points of their endpoints isn't always the case that there is a red edge?

Comment: I presume "four red edges" is referring to edges which have $x$ as one endpoint.  Thus $X$ contains $y$ and $z$ which are the endpoints (other than $x$) of the red edges $xy$ and $xz$.   So $xy$ and $xz$ are red, and you just said $yz$ is red, so that makes a red triangle $xyz$.